# How to put an App Edit for Under review with NodeJS in Google Play using the androidpublisher v3

Tags: android, node.js, automation, google-play, androidpublisher

My goal is to fully automate the whole process of publish new updates for my apps, I have hundreds of apps and I've created the aab for each of them automatically, that's the context.
Now I've created a NodeJS API to publish these aab and there is an endpoint to create an Edit using the `androidpublisher` as well. the code is this:

```js
    const releaseNotes = [
     {
      language: 'pt-BR',
      text: note,
     },
    ];

    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: `${serviceAccountPath}\\${projectName}.json`,
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'],
    });

    const androidPublisher = google.androidpublisher({
      version: 'v3',
      auth: auth,
    });

    // Step 1: Create a new edit
    const insertResp = await androidPublisher.edits.insert({
      packageName: pack,
    });

    const editId = insertResp.data.id;

    // Step 2: Upload the AAB
    const aabStream = createReadStream(aab);
    const uploadResponse = await androidPublisher.edits.bundles.upload({
      editId: editId,
      packageName: pack,
      media: {
        mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
        body: aabStream,
      },
    });
    console.info('AAB upload response:', uploadResponse.data);

    // Step 3: Update the release track
    const trackUpdateResponse = await androidPublisher.edits.tracks.update({
      editId: editId,
      packageName: pack,
      track: trackMode,
      requestBody: {
        releases: [
          {
            status: 'completed',
            releaseNotes: releaseNotes,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
    console.info('Track update response:', trackUpdateResponse.data);

    // Step 4: Validate the Edit
    const validateResponse = await androidPublisher.edits.validate({
      packageName: pack,
      editId: editId,
    });
    console.info('Validation response:', validateResponse.data);


    // Step 5: Commit the changes: it only Add an app bundle into the library
    const commitResponse = await androidPublisher.edits.commit({
      packageName: pack,
      editId: editId,
      changesNotSentForReview: false,
    });
    console.info('Commit response:', commitResponse.data);

    // there is a Step 6?
```

So I want to know how can I put the bundle added to the library into the google revision, to it go live fully programatically. Am I missing some step? or some detail? or doing something wrong? this is inside a simple async function that receive these arguments. this code works but doesn't do the full process that I need it to do, as I mention the idea is to fully automate the process of publish an update for an app.

A plus question is should I use the callback way to handle this process instead of await/async? I mean instead of async/await could I use the then().catch() it's pretty ugly that's why I'm not using it here but if this solve the issue I'm glad to know why and how.

Comment: I've also add set the changesNotSentForReview to False